# Carousel caption in thumbnail image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am wanting to use captions over images like in the carousel captions [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) but on images within thumbnails.

I have tried copying inserting a div within a thumbnail with the class "carousel-caption" to test this. I have changed the styles so that the position is not absolute and the margin is negative so it overlays the image but the caption loses its background.

Here is the example css

```
.carousel-caption {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
margin-top: -30px;
padding: 10px 15px 5px;
```

}

And here is an example of what I have done
http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/73/

How can I get the caption to overlay the image like it is in the carousel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per i understand that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/162/ . Write like this:

```
legend {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

}

.media-grid a {position:relative;}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. Sorry that jsfiddle was the wrong one. I have updated the correct jsfiddle with your fixes here http://jsfiddle.net/Yb22t/ . The only problem I am having is that the caption is over handing the image on the right... Any ideas why?